# PHP Creating a file on the server via controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir

I have the following code but it does not seem to be creating a folder at all.

Should I be using `is_dir` instead of `file_exists`?

```
        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_assets/quote/uploads/';

        $folderName = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyName;
        $folderName = str_replace(" ", "_", $folderName);
        $folderName = strtolower($folderName);

        if(!file_exists($folderName))
        {   
            mkdir($location.$folderName, 0777);

        }else{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if (!file_exists($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($location.$folderName, 0777);
}
```

Comment: That's redundant. If a file exists, mkdir won't overwrite it.  And is_dir will return true if the directory exists.  Therefore, you can just use one of them.

Comment: @corbin what would you recommend using?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Depends what your end goal is.  Would you want to delete a file and create a directory in its place?  If you just want to create a directory if it doesn't exist and you know that a file with the desired name will never exist, then I would go with is_dir.  Really they're both functionally equivalent in that situation.  When it would matter would be if a file may actually exist that has desired directory name.

Comment: @cobin I am just trying to create an empty folder the upload comes in the else statement

Answer (score 0):

is_dir function only detect if defined path is folder. Probably, you have not sufficient rights to create folder. Try to use

```
<?php
if (is_writable($dir)) {
echo "Path is writable";
}
?>
```

to detect if really your path is writable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be permission issue. Check do you have write permission in the directory where you are using mkdir.

Also use

```
echo $location.$folderName ;
```

to check it's happening at right place.

Hope this help.